# ValueError: 'invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go struct field TransactionArgs.chainId of type *hexutil.Big'

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, web, solidity

estoy intentando hacer un deploy de un contrato en Rinkeby y me salta el error del titulo. Es raro, ya que comprobe varias veces que no solo el chain_id usado, el address y la private key sean correctas, sino tambien la direccion http usada (estoy usando infura.io para hacer el deploy en la testnet). Dejo mas abajo el codigo del programa que se encargaria de hacer el deploy. No tengo una pista muy clara sobre como proceder frente a esto, ya que no es un error muy comun en ETH. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
from eth_utils import address
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from web3 import Web3
import web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


install_solc("0.8.7")
load_dotenv()

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()
    # print(simple_storage_file)


compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.8.7",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# Para deployar el contrato, se debe conseguir primero el bytecode y el ABI del contrato en cuestion
# Esto se hace recorriendo el JSON generado por la funcion anterior.

# Bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# ABI
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

# Conexion a ganache. Todos estos datos son de estas wallets y blockchain falsas generadas por el programa
w3 = Web3(
    Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/1819031aa0a14faebdef32c939f18e34")
)
chain_id = 4
# Dejar asi el chainid, la ui de ganache tiene una falla y muestra otro numero que no es el real
my_address = "0xE6761094Ee5D37b5710AE43BE9fAEc2B6cCff4CC"
# ESTO ES UNA MALA PRACTICA, NUNCA PONER LA PRIVATE KEY EN EL CODIGO
# private_key = "a702808ad2a12bfef6065454c84b4604bd11d84f5f05ca8e7bcc1cf2cb6b0a19"
# en cambio, hacer esto, que obtiene la private desde el archivo .env
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")


# Creacion del contrato a deployar
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

# Obtener el numero de la ultima transaccion realizada
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
# esto indica que se obtenga la ultima transaccion realizada desde esta address

# Proceso para realizar una transaccion
# 1. Construir la transaccion
# 2. Firmar la transaccion
# 3. Enviar la transaccion

# Transaccion
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {"chainId": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce}
)

# Firma
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)

# Enviado de transaccion
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
# Para hacer que la transaccion espere la confirmacion del bloque (opcional en Ganache)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)


# Trabajar con un contrato
# Se necesita el ABI y la address
simple_storage = w3.eth.contract(address=tx_receipt.contractAddress, abi=abi)
# Metodo Call -> se usa para que devuelva un valor, no realiza ningun cambio permanente en la blockchain
# Metodo Transact -> realiza cambios permanentes en la blockchain

# Esta funcion permite saber el valor inicial de la funcion Favorite Number (escrita en SimpleStorage.sol)
# print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())

# Esta permite cambiar el valor de la funcion Favorite Number
# ESTA ES UNA TRANSACCION COMO CUALQUIER OTRA, VER COMO ES EL PROCESO (ES EL MISMO)
store_transaction = simple_storage.functions.store(15).buildTransaction(
    {"chainID": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce + 1}
)
signed_store_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    store_transaction, private_key=private_key
)
send_store_tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_store_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_store_tx)
```

Comment: Dando palos de ciego... ¿será que sobra el `0x` al inicio del address?

Comment: Sabes que me lo cuestione eso, y no. En el tutorial (y por haber probado tambien) no funciona sin el 0x. Vi por ahi que podria ser por el http, pero no tiene sentido porque lo estoy corriendo desde Infura y no me tira ningun error en la pag.